# Upgrading jQuery 1.7.1

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am programming using asp.net MVC 4 under visual studio 2010 and currently i am using jQuery 1.7.1 as I have seen in Scripts folder so I would like to upgrade it to 1.10.2. Could anyone tell me exactly the steps needed to upgrade from 1.7.1 to 1.10.2 in visual studio? I am completely newbie on it.
Also, some people says that MVC does not recommend using jQuery and I am wondering why. Why is it not recommended in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery runs on the client side, MVC affects the server side.  My point being is they have nothing to do with each other and anybody who says jQ is not MVC friendly does not fully grasp the goal of MVC to begin with.

In regards to upgrading to a new jQuery, since you are probably using Visual Studio, it's best to use the built in NUGET updating, by running a simple NUGET command found here:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery

Nuget is built into Visual Studio 2012 but if you have 2010 you might need to install it:
http://www.nuget.org/

After you've ran the command you might want to double check all your references are pointing to 1.10.2 by looking at your master page and seeing what jQuery you are pointing to.  You might want to do a solution wide search for "1.7.1" and update any references that got missed.

It's important to test anything that uses jQuery, especially any pages that use a jQuery plugin, as you'll need to update that plugin also.  If you come across any jQuery items that don't work in the new version, you can also use this plugin that patches most of the changes from older jQuery to jQuery 1.10:
http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/